# 'auto' keyword vs auto storage class in C++?

Tags: c++, auto

I am confused between the two - is there a difference?

I learnt that auto storage class is the default storage class for all local variables, and the 'auto' keyword is use for type inference of defined variable: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/the-auto-keyword/.

But both of them use the keyword 'auto' : so is there a difference and how does the compiler tell so?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is too simple or a duplicate - because of which it has been given a downvote. I am seriously confused about this - the two uses seem different - yet how will the compiler know if I type auto x; for type inference or for auto storage class.

Comment: Not sure why your question was downvoted, but C++11 redefined `auto`.  The old (redundant) use of `auto` as a storage class specifier is no longer supported in C++11.  The compiler differentiates them by the language version.